# IRC server for Windows?

Tags: windows, cygwin, irc

I would like to run an IRC server for users of my LAN, and my best option would be to do so on a Windows XP box.  Is there a decent Windows/Cygwin IRC server that you have used and would recommend?  If so, any configuration pointers would also be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Anybody remember the Microsoft IRC server (obviously, for Windows)? Heh heh... It actually existed.

Comment: @Evan, never heard of it, and it seems to have been purged from the memory of Google too! Interestingly though this(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Comic_Chat) wikipedia artical explains the source of the horrific font Comic Sans MS.

Comment: @Farseeker: Microsoft Exchange 2000 Chat Server, http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315210 and http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc767140.aspx. I never saw it used in "production", but there was a chapter in the Exchange 2000 training I taught on it. No kidding...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've played around with the Windows build of [Unreal IRCd](http://www.unrealircd.com/). It's annoying to configure if you've never configured a Unixy IRC server before, but there's always the website to help you out, and on the plus side you get portable knowledge (all the concepts as well as most config files can be ported straight to a Unix machine.)

Answer (score 5):

InspIRCd is awsome, there's stable Win32 port/build nowadays.
SSL support and everything.

http://www.inspircd.org/

Answer (score 4):

I'd agree with Mihai that the Unreal IRCd has a lot of advantages.

If you don't like it for any reason, there's also [ignitionServer](http://www.ignition-project.com/pages/projects/).

Comment: `NOTICE: This domain name expired on 01/06/2013 and is pending renewal or deletion.`

Answer (score 2):

There is an IRCd for Windows called RockIRCd-win32 that isn't very well known, but it's great. I've been using it for a few months and have had no problems. I don't know if there's an official webpage for it, but the author had posted a direct link to a .zip file containing the binary and source code on a forum.

http://rubbermallet.org/rockircd-win32-vb6.zip

It was written from scratch, and not based on any existing server. I have it running on an old Windows 2000 computer with a Pentium 1, and the uptime is over a month and a half now so it seems reliable enough.

Answer (score 2):

Beware ircd is another choice http://ircd.bircd.org/